# What do both nulls mean in vue ref<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

What do each of these nulls mean in vue ref?

```
const submitButton = ref<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first null is part of the type (which is defined between angle brackets <>).

Meaning that the value of this ref()
can be **either** a HTMLButton Element, **or** null.

The second null is the value of the ref that is initially being set.

So submitButton is a ref that can either be a buttonelement or null and it is currently null.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ref()` as a reactive value, you can specify its type with `<>`

- `submitButton` can two types: `HTMLButtonElement` & `null`.
- `submitButton`'s initial(or default) value is `null`.

More information on Vue reactivity  https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

You might want to look up some basic TypeScript concepts.